# Classifier and Technique to use for large number of categories

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, categories

I am designing a scikit learn classifier which has 5000+ categories and training data is at least 80 million and may grow upto an additional 100 million each year. I have already tried with all the categories but it generates classifiers in the order of 100s of GBs binary file. So I think that having one classifier for each category would be helpful and would also help me to fine tune features for each category thereby improving accuracy, but this means 5k+ classifiers for each of these categories. So how to handle this large data requirements and which incremental classifiers to use for this case , considering the fact that I will keep on getting additional training data as well as may discover new categories?

**Update :**

The number of features are about 45 which are mostly text based and most are categorical with text based values with large cardinality i.e many features may have huge number of possible values and available RAM IS 32gb with 8 core CPU. I tried Multinomial NB and linear SGD with sparse matrices which are extremely sparse. Used the scikit learns Dictvectorizer to vectorize the feature dictionary. Also will pandas dataframes help to optimize the overall configuration?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you tried? What kind of classifier generates binary files in the order of 100s of GB? Also it would be nice to know how many features you have (and if there's text data for instance) and how much RAM you can afford to use.

Comment: @Idirer have updated

Comment: Thanks for the update. A SGD logistic regression with some l1 penalty should give a sparse (this lighter) model. 100GB is huge, so I'm guessing you're talking about your entire pipeline? When you talk about "binary file", you're using pickle to dump your model?

Comment: @Idirer Yes to both questions

Comment: Ok. Can you also tell us about the elements in your pipeline ;)? It's quite likely that you are dumping a lot of unnecessary elements that end up taking a lot of space. A good way to "profile" this would be to dump each step in the pipeline separately to see which ones are taking the most space. 
You could also try using `joblib.dump` as a replacement for pickle.

Comment: No there are many necessary elements as categories itself are 5k + and each feature value has possibly thousands of possible values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89681/discussion-between-ldirer-and-stackit).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up our discussion:

#### Incremental classifiers

"Incremental" classifiers are good candidates when you need to do out-of-core learning (i.e all your data does not fit in memory).
For classification in scikit-learn you mentionned `MultinomialNB` and `SGDClassifier`, which are the two main classifiers that implement the `partial_fit` api.

For your purposes it seems like an *online learning* algorithm would be perfect. You can look into **VowpalWabbit** if you want to go that way. I had a chance to use it for a similar problem (6k+ classes) and the models were way lighter than 100GBs. I don't recall the exact size but I was able to store a bunch of them on my personal computer ;).

Note that documentation for VW is a bit scarce (nothing like scikit-learn) and you'll probably have to read some papers if you have a sophisticated use case. Here's [a good tutorial](http://zinkov.com/posts/2013-08-13-vowpal-tutorial/) to get started.

#### Size of the pickled model

Your entire pickled pipeline is in the order of 100GBs, this looks huge to me. I'd advise pickling each step separately as a way to profile the issue.
Sometimes you can drop some attributes before you pickle the estimators. An example is `stop_words_` for a `TfidfVectorizer` (see [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)).
If the steps are storing large numpy arrays, `joblib.dump` (`from sklearn.externals import joblib`) can be a more memory-efficient alternative to pickle.

#### Training many binary classifiers

You probably don't want the overhead of having to care for 5k+ classifiers yourself. What you are describing is a **One Versus All** strategy to performing multiclass classification.
Note that when using `LogisticRegression` or `SGDClassifier` this is already how the multiclass problem is being solved.

#### Conclusion

I'd say VowpalWabbit looks like a perfect fit, but there might be other tools out there for your use case.

For your last point: pandas won't help on making lighter models, it's a great library to manipulate/transform the data though.